# Segmentation Fault while running PAM functions

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to C and cannot figure out why this program seg faults. 
It could be a stupid error on my behalf but cannot seem to figure it out.

I also know its unusual using the embedding method I am, but this was down for sheer familiarity with Python3 and the ease of use.

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#define PAM_SM_AUTH
#define PAM_SM_ACCOUNT
//#define PAM_SM_SESSION

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include </usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h>

/* expected hook */
/*
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    printf("Acct mgmt\n");
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
*/

/* expected hook, this is where custom stuff happens */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv )

{
    chdir("../code/facial"); // this changes it to the correct directory to execute

    dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so",RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    Py_Initialize(); // Starts python interpreter
    PyRun_SimpleString("import os\nimport sys\nsys.path.append(os.getcwd())"); // lets python know where we are


    PyObject *mymod, *func1, *ret1;


    mymod = PyImport_ImportModule("pam_detect"); // This is the .py

    if (mymod != 0){ // check if the file file was loaded
        func1 =  PyObject_GetAttrString(mymod, "detect"); // hel is the function name in the file you declared earlier
        ret1 = PyObject_CallObject(func1, NULL); // Null because the function doesnt take an argument.
        if (ret1 == 1){
            Py_Finalize();
            return PAM_SUCCESS;
        }
        else{
            Py_Finalize();
            return PAM_AUTH_ERR;

        }

    }

    else{
            //printf("Error: can't find file!\n");
            return 1;
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont know where it seg faults , I have just been following the PAM docs as closely as possible http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the pointers but haven't assigned them to a memory address.

```c
PyObject *mymod, *func1, *ret1;
```

This line in your code makes a pointer named mymod which can point to a memory containing PyObject, but you haven't given the memory address to it yet.

I don't know if calling the functions will return pointers correctly or not,  So when you try to put anything there, it gives segmentation fault if you are trying to assign a variable to a pointer without a memory address.

I can only say this much without knowing where the fault occurred. try putting printf statement before assigning of all 3 pointers and see.

Comment: it was solved? at least mention where the fault was, I can't check it because I don't have those headers. It'll be beneficial to other people who might get this same problem